# $wpdb MySQL select from main table and join each row with two rows of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

$referrer is the only defined variable.

main_table holds the relationship between users and referrers. a referrer can have many users.

```
user_id  | referrer
1        | seller
2        | abother seller
3        | another seller
4        | seller
```

secondary_table holds user_id, meta_key and meta_value with last_name and first_name being meta_keys.

```
user_id  | meta_key   | meta_value
1        | first_name | John
1        | last_name  | Doe
4        | first_name | Betty
4        | last_name  | Boo
```

I need to merge the following 3 queries

```
SELECT user_id FROM main_table WHERE referrer = $referrer

SELECT meta_value FROM secondary_table WHERE user_id = $user_id AND meta_key = first_name

SELECT meta_value FROM secondary_table WHERE user_id = $user_id AND meta_key = last_name
```

into one query so I can use it with $results = $wpdb->get_results, then asort() the $results by last_name to have an alphabetically ordered output and echo $results with a foreach like

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
  echo $result->user_id.' '.$result->first_name.' '.$result->last_name;
}
```

If $referrer == "seller" the output should look like this:

```
4 Betty Boo
1 John Doe
```

How should that single query look like?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
select
  main_table.user_id,
  concat(s1.meta_value, ' ', s2.meta_value) as name
from
  main_table left join secondary_table s1
  on main_table.user_id = s1.user_id and s1.meta_key = 'first_name'
  left join secondary_table s2
  on main_table.user_id = s2.user_id and s2.meta_key = 'last_name'
where
  referrer = $referrer
```

I'm joining `main_table` with `secondary_table twice`, the first time filtered on the first name, the second time filtered on the last name. Then to get the name you just have to concat the first meta_value with the second.

Answer (score 0):

Its little bit tricky. You can use following query

```
select m.user_id as new_user_id, s1.meta_value as new_first_name, s2.meta_value as new_last_name from main_table m, secondary_table s1, secondary_table s2 where m.user_id=s1.user_id and m.user_id=s2.user_id and s1.meta_key='first_name' and s2.meta_key='last_name' and m.referrer='seller' order by new_last_name
```

and then u can do

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(...)  
foreach ($results as $result) {
      echo $result->new_user_id.' '.$result->new_first_name.' '.$result->new_last_name;
    }
```